# Java download file from server cannot identify file type

Tags: java, download

Below is the controller for downloading files. The files can be multiple types, such as PDF, excel and doc. The issue is that the file type downloaded is always "File" instead of `.pdf`, `.excel` or `.doc`. I have to manually choose a application to open the file. Does anyone know what is wrong?

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/download/system-of-record", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void systemOfRecordDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) throws IOException {
    int formId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    Form form = formService.findFormByPrimaryKey(formId);
    String formName = form.getName();
    String formPath = form.getInternalLink();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + formName + "\"");
    
    try {
        File f = new File(formPath);
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

        int readByte = 0;

        while ((readByte = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
            os.write(buf, 0, readByte);
            os.flush();
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you have set the mime type to octet-stream

Either use [Files.probeContentType(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to get the correct mime type of the file object and replace it in place of octet-stream

Or use your own logic to specify a mime type there from [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/) list

Comment: Hi. I used your method and actually it can identify the mime type (eg. pdf) from path but the downloaded file from the application is still "File" instead of PDF...

Comment: Did you use application/pdf ?

Comment: And does the downloaded filename still have .pdf in it?

Comment: PDF is just an example. The file can be pdf, excel or doc. I can't just use application/pdf. But your method can identify mime type from path. It's just the download file does not pick up the mime type...not sure why...

Comment: I understood that, just wanted to know what goes wrong in the example of using a pdf

Comment: The file name is entered by user when they upload the form so it does not have extension. It's from database. Do I need to use the actual file name stored in the server?

Comment: You mean there is no file extension when you save it? That kinda presents the problem to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149030/discussion-between-sophia-wu-and-joey-pinto).

Comment: It is because of the form name. It does not have extension.

Comment: @SophiaWu Why is there no extension? Where did it go?

Comment: I used the form name from database which was entered when uploading the form so it doesn't have extension. I didn't use the actual download file name.